Не работает цикл, помогите
По идее тут должно все войти в цикл s, умножиться на 10, отсортироваться и показать, по выводу он мне цикл 6 раз прописывает, я новичок, можете сказать что тут не так? У меня во всем хорошо идёт но циклы не очень
s = [0]
q = int(input('Введите любое число:'))
s.append(int(q))
w = int(input('Введите любое число:'))
s.append(int(w))
e = int(input('Введите любое число:'))
s.append(int(e))
r = int(input('Введите любое число:'))
s.append(int(r))
t = int(input('Введите любое число:'))
s.append(int(t))
for x in s:
    x = int(x) * 10
    s.sort()
    print(s)


Ну как минимум сразу можно сказать, что редактировать тот же самый список, по которому выполняется цикл — крайне сомнительная затея

s = []
q = int(input('Введите любое число:'))
s.append(q)  # не нужно ещё раз вызывать int
w = int(input('Введите любое число:'))
s.append(w)
e = int(input('Введите любое число:'))
s.append(e)
r = int(input('Введите любое число:'))
s.append(r)
t = int(input('Введите любое число:'))
s.append(t)
for i in range(len(s)):  # перебираем числа по индексам списка
    s[i] = s[i] * 10

# печатаем и сортируем вне цикла
s.sort()
print(s)


Кстати, считывание чисел можно сделать гораздо короче (это list comprehension):
s = [int(input('Введите любое число:')) for _ in range(5)]

или, понятней
s = []
for _ in range(5):
    s.append(int(input('Введите любое число:')))


Огромное спасибо

@КириллСемёнов, если этот ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как принятый (галка напротив ответа).

Тогда уж сразу как-то типа print(sorted(int(input('Введите любое число:')) for _ in range(5)))

@CrazyElf, пожалейте ТС, он ещё циклы-то не очень знает...

@CrazyElf, кстати, в вашем коде не хватает * 10.

Да, забыл точно )
